# Add list data to list (LINQ?) in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I did some search of this, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have two lists in C#.

```
public class ETransaccion
    {
        public int Sistema { get; set; }
        public int Caja { get; set; }
        public int Tienda { get; set; }
        public int Lapos { get; set; }
        public int Visadebito { get; set; }
        public int Amex { get; set; }
        public int Visa { get; set; }
        public int Credencial { get; set; }
        public int Nvisa { get; set; }
        public int Maestro { get; set; }
        public int Cabal { get; set; }
        public int Tshop { get; set; }
        public int Credial { get; set; }
        public int Master { get; set; }
        public int Italcred { get; set; }
        public int Tshopvisa { get; set; }
        public int Diners { get; set; }
        public int Naranja { get; set; }
        public int Seriepinpad { get; set; }
    }

public class EPinpads
    {
        public int Tienda { get; set; }
        public int Sistema { get; set; }
        public int Caja { get; set; }
        public int Seriepinpad { get; set; }
    }
```

So I need to insert the Seriepinpad property of EPinpads list in the ETRansaccion list matching Sistema, Caja and Tienda.

I think I can do this using LINQ, but the stuff online didn't help much.

Comment: `ETransaccion.Seriepinpad = ETransaccion.Sistema`? Cant really get your problem!?

Comment: So to be clear, you have a list of ETransaccion and a list of EPinpads. You want to create a 3rd list which contains records with all information from ETransaccion and to add the Seriepinpad info as well where the Tienda, Sistema and Caja data match?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var list1 = new List<ETransaccion>();
var list2 = new List<EPinpads>();

list1.ForEach(
    (x) =>
        x.Seriepinpad =
            list2.Any(y => y.Sistema == x.Sistema && y.Tienda == x.Tienda && y.Caja == x.Caja) 
                ? list2.First(y => y.Sistema == x.Sistema && y.Tienda == x.Tienda && y.Caja == x.Caja)
                    .Seriepinpad
                : x.Seriepinpad);
```

Comment: Thanks James! That help a lot! :D

Comment: Instead of all the conditional operator (?:) part use x.Seriepinpad = list2.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Sistema == x.Sistema && y.Tienda == x.Tienda && y.Caja == x.Caja)?.Seriepinpad

Comment: I don't know if you're asking to me, but just to clarify, I'm not the downvoter @James Dev

Comment: Mirko that is only available in c# 6 so if @Tomas is using c#6 then what you suggested is a better option.